# Power BI - Remove first 7 digits of String

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to Remove the first 7 digits of a Text using DAX. I know that it's possible to use the `RIGHT` and `LEFT` function in Excel, so is there something similar in Power BI?

Answer (score 5):

In the Query Editor you can use `Transform->Split Column->By Number of Characters` and then use these settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [left function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/left-function-dax) is exactly the same in DAX. The following will give you the left 7 characters from a column:

```
LEFT(TableName[ColumnName], 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUBSTITUTE([ColumnName];LEFT([ColumnName]; 7);"")
```

Comment: It is always helpful add some explanation to your answer, to make it more clear and understandable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the RIGHT function. Since DAX is used to aggregate functions, I'll use SELECTEDVALUE() for this example. Substitute this with the desired aggregation function, otherwise use Power Query as described by mafioso's answer.

If the string has a fixed length, you can simply write:

`RIGHT( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ColumnName]); <length of column -7> )`

Otherwise, if the string has an unknown or variable length, you can let DAX calculate this for you:

`RIGHT( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ColumnName]); LEN( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ColumnName]) -7 ))`

LEN() calculates the length of a given string, so by subtracting 7 from the string length, you'll take everything from the string except the 7 first characters.